# Google Maps API Marker Visibility

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game where I want the user to find certain locations on the map. I have currently created the location for Chicago, but I would like the marker to be invisible. How would I do this?

```
function initMap() {
        var chicago = {lat: 41.8781, lng: -87.6298};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0},
          zoom: 1
});
        var chicagoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: chicago,
            map: map
});
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the marker in the JS memory, but remove it from the map, you can set the map to null in the marker object:

```
chicagoMarker.setMap(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way of setVisible is `marker.setVisible(false);`

Comment: I'm not sure if I put the code in the wrong place, but when I do that it makes the whole map invisible, not just the marker